# spring-kafka: How to provide RetryTopicConfiguration to ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have to set up Kafka consumers without using annotations. I have something like this:

```java
public class MyCustomListener<V> implements MessageListener<String, V> {
  private final String                          topicName;
  private final Class<V>                        recordType;
  private final String                          recordTypeName;
  private final KafkaProperties                 props;
  private final Logger logger;
  private final ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, V> listenerContainer;

  public MyCustomListener(
    @NotNull String topicName,
    @NotNull Class<V> recordType,
    @NotNull KafkaProperties props,
    Logger logger
  ) {
    this.topicName = topicName;
    this.recordType = recordType;
    this.recordTypeName = recordType.getSimpleName();
    this.props = props;
    this.logger = logger;
    this.listenerContainer = setup();
  }

  protected ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, V> setup() {
    logger.info("Setting up Kafka listener container for topic {}/{}", topicName, recordTypeName);

    var consumerFactory =
      new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        new HashMap<>() {{
          put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, props.getBootstrapServers());
          put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, props.getConsumer().getGroupId());
        }},
        new StringDeserializer(),
        new MyDataDeserializer<>()
      );

    var containerProps = new ContainerProperties(topicName);
    containerProps.setMessageListener(this);

    var container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, containerProps);
    container.start();
    return container;
  }

  @Override
  public final void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, V> record) {
    logger.info(
      "(#{}) Received {} message in Kafka: ({})",
      Thread.currentThread().getId(),
      recordTypeName,
      record.key()
    );

    # Actual processing of record code here ...
  }
}
```

The above works for the most part.

> How do I associate/provide `RetryTopicConfiguration` to the above setup? So that I am able to publish to retry topic and DLT topics and backoff as specified in the retry config.

I am fine with just the retry topic config part being a `Bean`, say:

```java
public RetryTopicConfiguration myRetryTopicConfig(
    KafkaProperties props,
    KafkaTemplate<String, MyData> template,
    ...
  ) {
  return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
    .newInstance()
    .fixedBackOff(..)
    .useSingleTopicForFixedDelays()
    ...
    .create(template);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such usage of RetryTopicConfiguration with manually created listeners / containers without `@KafkaListener` annotations is currently not supported:

> Currently, the non-blocking retries mechanism is built around @KafkaListener; you would have to do a lot of manual wiring to set it up with manually created container(s).
> We hope to make it easier for such use cases in future, perhaps in 3.0.

You can upvote or comment [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2352) in the project's repository to show your interest - the `3.0` is due later this year.

Comment: ☹️ .. sad to know it is not supported. Will change course then. Upvoted the issue.

Comment: How to do this is now documented https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2352#issuecomment-128430431 supported on 2.9.x and later.